# How to do Rcheck with config file

Tags: r

I have a R package that can be configured via a **config.yml.**
This config.yml is on the **root** level of the project.

However, when doing **RCheck** there is an error:

```
error: Config file config.yml not found in current working directory or parent directories
```

Seems like the Rcheck does not find the config.yml. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html